# Delete contents of a directory recursively on Windows

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I need to delete the entire contents of a directory (nested folders and all) without deleting the directory itself. Recreating the directory after the fact is not an option as it is being locked by the running process and delete of it would fail.

So far I have the following:

```
rd /s /q dir1
rd /s /q dir2
rd /s /q dir3
del /q /f *
```

It works, but the obvious problem is that I have to update this script every time the set of first-level directories changes.

On UNIX, I would solve this like this:

```
rm -rf *
```

What is the Windows equivalent?

Comment: Didn't you try `rd /s /q dir/*` ?

Comment: This fails at least on Windows 2003 Server R2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming that you are executing the command from the top-level directory:

```
for /d %X in (*.*) do rd /s /q %X
```

If you are executing this from a script, you must use double percent signs:

```
for /d %%X in (*.*) do rd /s /q %%X
```

If you need to delete the files in the top-level directory as well, add this to the script:

```
del /q /f *
```

Comment: Note: inside a script use %%X instead.

Comment: @SAD - Thanks, added that to the answer.

Comment: This won't find (`for /d /r`) or delete (`rd`) any files in the top level directory. (It's unclear whether OP needs that?)

Comment: @Rudu: I think that could be fixed as easily as adding `del /q *` to the script.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will give this answer a try and accept if successful. My main problem is to remove reliance on manual listing of directories. I would be very happy with a two line script (one for folders and one for files at the top level).

Comment: I am accepting this answer. It is 99% correct and was certainly good enough for me to figure out the final solution. The only problem in this answer is that "for /d /r" should be just "for /d". Recursive directory listing is not necessary in the for loop and can lead to some interesting problems when executing rd.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, I've updated the answer to reflect your observations.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question with an old answer, but I've found a simpler way to do this and thought of sharing it.

You can step into the target directory and use the `rd` command. Since Windows will not allow you to delete any files or directories currently in use, and you are making use of the target directory by stepping into it, you'll delete all the contents, except the target directory itself.

```
cd mydir
rd /s /q .
```

You'll get a message saying:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

This will occur when, after deleting all the contents, the `rd` command fails to delete the current directory, because you're standing in it. But you'll see this is not an actual error if you echo the last exit code, which will be `0`.

```
echo %errorlevel%
0
```

It's what I'm using and it works fine. I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice answer, congratulations.

Comment: I like this answer (less code on screen) and it works for me in my Azure DevOps script just perfect :)    

Note: to suppress all output (incl. error(s)) append: > nul 2>&1